# undefined variable issue

Tags: jquery

I am having trubles getting a variable declared.

I have

```
function employees(){
   //init employees...;
}

employees.prototype.getName=function(){
            if(ajax.doingStuff){
                return;
            }               
        } 

$(document).ready(function(){
     var ajax=new ajaxCall();
     var people=new employees();   

     $('#option').on('change', function(){
                people.getName();                
       })        

})
```

and when I click `$('#option)` button, I got

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: ajax is not defined
```

Can anyone help me to solve this problem? Thanks a lot!

Comment: whoops. some other places. and my console.log ajax under document.ready response an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable `ajax` only exists within the scope of the function passed in to `ready()`.  If you want to use it elsewhere, you'll either have to pass a reference to that object (eg, pass in `ajax` as a parameter of the `getName` function), or move all code to the same scope.

For example:

```
var ajax=new ajaxCall();
```

Could be moved to the global scope, or:

```
function employees(){
   //init employees...;
}
```

Could be moved into the ready function.

Answer (score 3):

You have a scope issue.  The `ajax` variable is only available within the `ready` function.  You either need to move the `ajax` variable out of the `ready` function or move the code which uses it in.